# Inefficient code for removing duplicates from a list in Python - interpretation?

Tags: python

I am writing a Python program to remove duplicates from a list. My code is the following:

```
some_values_list = [2,2,4,7,7,8]
unique_values_list = []
for i in some_values_list:
        if i not in unique_values_list:
            unique_values_list.append(i)
print(unique_values_list)
```

This code works fine. However, an alternative solution is given and I am trying to interpret it (as I am still a beginner in Python). Specifically, I do not understand the added value or benefit of creating an empty set - how does that make the code clearer or more efficient? Isn´t it enough to create an empty list as I have done in the first example?

The code for the alternative solution is the following:

```
a = [10,20,30,20,10,50,60,40,80,50,40]

dup_items = set()
uniq_items = []
for x in a:
    if x not in dup_items:
        uniq_items.append(x)
        dup_items.add(x)

print(dup_items)
```

This code also throws up an error `TypeError: set() missing 1 required positional argument: 'items'` (This is from a website for Python exercises with answers key, so it is supposed to be correct.)

Comment: Checking if `item in some_list` is linear time because you need to do a linear search, making the whole algorithm quadratic time. Doing `item in some_set` is constant time, because Python sets are hash sets, making the whole operation linear time. That error I cannot reproduce, did you redefine `set` somewhere? Like `def set(items): ...`?

Comment: Not facing any error while running the code.

Comment: FYI: In case the order of your list does not matter, `list(set(a))` is probably the fastest way to clear the list `a` from all duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determining if an item is present in a set is generally faster than determining if it is present in a list of the same size. Why? Because for a set (at least, for a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), which is how CPython sets are implemented) we don't need to traverse the entire collection of elements to check if a particular value is present (whereas we do for a list). Rather, we usually just need to check at most one element. A more precise way to frame this is to say that containment tests for lists take "linear time" (i.e. time proportional to the size of the list), whereas containment tests in sets take "constant time" (i.e. the runtime does not depend on the size of the set).

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Can you please also explain to me how does Python know then that dup_items = set() in this example refers to list(a), since it does not include any arguments - it´s just an empty set?

Comment: @Madrid_datalady It is just an empty set at that point, with no relationship to `a`. It just gets used in the loop to store the items of `a` to keep track of what's been seen so far.

Comment: Ok... then why do we need to add or append non-duplicate items to both the set and the empty list? Isn´t this redundant, meaning wouldn´t just using the set do the job??

Comment: @Madrid_datalady Well the set is unordered, so if you don't care about order and just want to remove duplicates, then sure you don't need a list.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup for an element in a list takes O(N) time (you can find an element in logarithmic time, but the list should be sorted, so not your case). So if you use the same list to keep unique elements and lookup newly added ones, your whole algorithm runs in O(N²) time (N elements, O(N) average lookup). `set` is a hash-set in Python, so lookup in it should take O(1) on average. Thus, if you use an auxiliary set to keep track of unique elements already found, your whole algorithm will only take O(N) time on average, chances are good, one order better.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases sets are faster than lists. One of this cases is when you look for an item using "in" keyword. The reason why sets are faster is that, they implement hashtable.

So, in short, `if x not in dup_items` in second code snippet works faster than `if i not in unique_values_list`.

If you want to check the time complexity of different Python data structures and operations, you can check this [link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)
.
I think your code is also inefficient in a way that for each item in list you are searching in larger list. The second snippet looks for the item in smaller set. But that is not correct all the time. For example, if the list is all unique items, then it is the same.

Hope it clarifies.